# Is there an or case keys in json

Tags: json

I'm writing a program that takes a json file as input and with this json file there is some code running in background that gives the value. my json file is as below.

```
{
    "Machine Learning": {
        "URL1": "https://url1.com",
        "URL2": "https://url2.com",
        "URL3": "https://url3.com"
    },
    "ML": {
        "URL1": "https://url1.com",
        "URL1": "https://url2.com",
        "URL1": "https://url3.com"
    }
}
```

Here the response for both `ML` and `Machine Learning` is same.

This is working fine with out any issues, but I'm trying to do something like below.

```
{
   "Machine Learning || ML": {
        "URL1": "https://url1.com",
        "URL2": "https://url2.com",
        "URL3": "https://url3.com"
    }
}
```

Basically my aim is to combine similar keywords for making a NLP type model. 
I just want to know, if this can be done. Again, my current model is working fine, I'm here to get opinions from experts on if the I can have an or type values in json. if so, how can I get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in JSON, no. JSON has no concept of combining two entries, or referring to one entry from another. There are extensions to JSON that do the latter, but JSON itself is intentionally *very* simple.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, So this means simple that there should be a separate entry like the way I'm using it currently?

Comment: @user3872094: Probably. Another option would be to add your own concept of references via a replacer you pass to `JSON.stringify` and a reviver you pass to `JSON.parse`. Then the JSON+ (as it were) could be something like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/cWti0KrH You can read up on replacers and revivers on MDN's [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) pages.

Comment: This is awesome @T.J. Crowder, I'll try this out. Thanks